# Margin of a TabPanel via TabControl.Resources

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do we set the Margin of a TabPanel via TabControl.Resources, I tryed this code:

```
                    <TabControl.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="500,0,0,0" />
                        </Style>
                    </TabControl.Resources>
                </TabControl>
```

But this doesn't work for some reason while setting its width does work:

```
                <TabControl.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="500" />
                        </Style>
                    </TabControl.Resources>
                </TabControl>
```

For the moment I have set margin with a Template but I would like to edit it for one separate TabControl.

Thanks Mikael Törnqvist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify the margin for the `TabPanel` within the `Template` of the `TabControl`

like:

```
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                        (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="#FFAAAAAA" />
                      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Panel.ZIndex="1"
                        Margin="500,0,4,-1"
                        IsItemsHost="True"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                        Background="Transparent" />
              <Border x:Name="Border"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      BorderThickness="1"
                      CornerRadius="2"
                      KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                      KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                      KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">
                <Border.Background>
                  <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                       StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ContentAreaColorLight}"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ContentAreaColorDark}"
                                  Offset="1" />
                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}"/>
                </Border.BorderBrush>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                  Margin="4"
                                  ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, That was a bit of code for that margin!

Comment: Ah I guess the TabPanel needs something to refer to while setting the Margin!

Comment: Yeah, the reason why is because you still want to maintain the default Template, so in order to do so, you need to provide the "default" Template settings as well. I got the default template from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137(v=vs.110).aspx